# Encrypt Decrypt the Environment Variables

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

Is it recommended to encrypt the .env file or the passwords inside .env file?

Because they don't want the database passwords to be in plain text.
They said that it is for security reasons. I am using laravel and the user does only have access in public folder. I've already hidden the phpinfo.php file.

Thanks

Comment: Who are "they"? If you're going to encrypt the file, how are you going to decrypt it (where do you store decryption key)?

Comment: That's what I wanted to ask to, How am I going to decrypt the file, but if it just the password. Maybe encrypt in .env then decrypt in config?

Comment: Anything related to encryption has to do with hiding certain information from certain parties for certain reasons, and managing the key to unlocking those secrets accordingly. So, you first need to define who the involved parties are here, whom you want to hide the password from and how that someone might gain access to the password in the first place. … I'll wait…

Comment: I don't know whom they want to hide the password. For example one of my password in .env is 'aaabbbccc123' but they want it to be encrypted. Maybe I'll just set an encrypted string then decrypt it in config folder. Thanks for answering. I'll remember it.

Comment: If an unauthorized user has access to your `.env` file you've got much bigger problems on your hands than an unencrypted password...

Comment: Maybe that's what they want. Just make the string encrypted so that if the somebody looks on it, they cannot get the password right away. They need to decrypt it. Thanks.

Comment: If anyone can get access to the extent that they can see the contents of the environment, they usually also have access to all the information required to decrypt it. So this is useless security theatre. That's why I pointed out that you first need to define the attack you're trying to protect from here. The correct response to "them" is likely "bugger off, this makes no sense."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set an [encrypted](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/encryption) string as password in the '.env' file and decrypt it in your code. But I don't think that it will increase the security level on your system.

Much more important is to set the right configuration on the server (permissions, file locations, etc.).
You could disable things like`phpinfo()` and instead of .env, you could use [php-fpm pool](https://medium.com/@tomahock/passing-system-environment-variables-to-php-fpm-when-using-nginx-a70045370fad) conf and protect the file from only being viewed by root .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is it  the encrypted password won't increase the security level?

Is using php-fpm pool best practice for security purposes?

Comment: @LordGrim Surely if they can get to your `.env` file they could get to the encryption keys as well which does not make for a good security measure.

Comment: That's what I think. It's my first time hearing encrypting environment variables. What I know is that the purpose of env file is to hide the credentials you are using to the public, so passwords, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Sapnesh Naik. Maybe I'll just comply to what they want. Make the string encrypted then just decrypt it when using the variable in my code.